# Adding a warning message to an aspx page

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have an asp.net application in which i have to add a warning javascript message when i click into button in my Gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField  >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="Ref"  runat="server" value='<%#Eval("Ref")%>'   ></asp:HiddenField>

                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="Savebtn" runat="server" Text="update"  OnClick="gv_RowEditing"/>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Note">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="note"  runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Note")%>'  onfocus="this.style.color='red'" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="max">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="maxtxt" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("prix max")%>' onfocus="this.style.color='red'"/>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="min"  >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="mintxt" runat="server"  Text='<%#Eval("prix min")%>' onfocus="this.style.color='red'"/>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
  <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />


        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BorderColor="Yellow" Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#FF3300" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

I need to add an alert when i click into the button `savebtn`, if `maxtxt` value is less than `mintxt` value , an warning message appears.

- How can i do this?
- What is the differents ways to add an alert message to an aspx page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `OnClientClick` event to call a Javascript method to validate your fields.

```
<asp:Button ID="Savebtn" runat="server" Text="update"  OnClick="gv_RowEditing"
       OnClientClick="if ( ! ValidateFields()) return false;"/>
```

Your javascript method: (Not 100% sure of syntax but you get the idea)

```
function ValidateFields() {

    var maxtxt = document.getElementById("<%=maxtxt.ClientID%>").Value;
    var mintxt = document.getElementById("<%=mintxt.ClientID%>").Value; 

     if ( maxtxt < mintxt ) {
        alert("This is bad");
        return false;
     }

     return true;


}
```

Comment: I think OP doesn't need an alert but a message on page itself, in something like `span` etc...

Comment: They said they want `alert`.  They don't specify what type of alert/msg.

Comment: He said "Message on aspx page".

Comment: I got this error `'maxtxt' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level`

Answer (score 1):

Use the OnClientClick function of the Button to specify some JavaScript to run before the postback occurs.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClientClick='MyFunction();' OnClick="Button1_Click" />


function MyFunction()
{
var maxtxt = document.getElementById("<%=maxtxt.ClientID%>").Value;
var mintxt = document.getElementById("<%=mintxt.ClientID%>").Value; 

if ( maxtxt < mintxt ) {
    alert("You did something wrong!");
   }
}
```

Often, you simply want to confirm some action on the client side before it gets to the server side

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClientClick='return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?");' OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

You can combine the two...

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClientClick='return MyFunction();' OnClick="Button1_Click" />

function MyFunction()
{
var maxtxt = document.getElementById("<%=maxtxt.ClientID%>").Value;
var mintxt = document.getElementById("<%=mintxt.ClientID%>").Value; 

 if ( maxtxt < mintxt ) {
    return confirm("Are you sure you want to do that");
 }

 return true;
}
```

Comment: I got this error `'maxtxt' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level`

Answer (score 0):

```
 <asp:Button ID="Savebtn" runat="server" Text="update"  OnClick="gv_RowEditing"/>

 function gv_RowEditing(){
     if(parseInt($('#maxTxt').val()) < parseInt($('#minTxt').val())){
        alert("you message");
     }
 }
```

or

```
$("#Savebtn").click(function() {
   if(parseInt($('#maxTxt').val()) < parseInt($('#minTxt').val())){
        alert("you message");
     }
});
```

This is using jquery.

Comment: I downvoted because you used server side OnClick instead of client side OnClientClick.

Answer (score 0):

Define your gridview as follows:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField  >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="Ref"  runat="server" value='<%#Eval("Ref")%>'   ></asp:HiddenField>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="Savebtn" runat="server" Text="update"  OnClick="gv_RowEditing"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Note">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="note"  runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Note")%>'  onfocus="this.style.color='red'" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="max">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="maxtxt" maxtxt="1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("prix max")%>' onfocus="this.style.color='red'"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="min"  >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="mintxt" mintxt="1" runat="server"  Text='<%#Eval("prix min")%>' onfocus="this.style.color='red'"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

         <asp:TemplateField>
             <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:Button CommandName="Update" Text="Update" OnClientClick="return Validate();"  />
             </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
    <EditRowStyle BorderColor="Yellow" Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#FF3300" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Then include the following js (using jquery):

```
function Validate(){
   var max = $("input[maxtxt]").val();
   var min = $("input[mintxt]").val();
   if (maxtxt < mintxt){
       alert("Something wrong!!");
       return false;
   }
   else{
       return true;
   }
}
```